# What scriptures talk of difference in leaving the body consciously and unconsciously which is death?

Tags: atma, death

We have reference on what happens after death and before next birth of the soul. What will be the experience of us,as per ancient texts and how we will be if we leave this body at will, and leave this body as death without consciousness.

Comment: Asking users about how will be the experience will make this question opinion based .As there will be lot's of speculations ,and will generate multiple views. Instead ask about what scripture is saying about this.

Comment: Ok i will edit the question to make it clear. Can you give reference on any ancient scripture talking about in difference in soul leaving the body?

Comment: I have seen videos talking about soul exiting through Sahasra for Moksha, but how does soul leave the body at death? I think I haven't had an answer when I searched everywhere for it.

Comment: Yes , I will try but mostly we will not be getting exact descriptive answer .Will need to construct it using multiple sources and stories related to topic.